# Disable node summary page on /node path

Tags: 7, path-aliases, nodes

I want to disable the default front page, that is showing a list of nodes. I use another front page but it is still displayed at the url `example.com/node`. Either restricting access or redirecting to the front page would be fine.

My homepage is currently set to `/home` (which gets nicely rewritten to `example.com/`). Now I have already tried a few different things.

- Under `/admin/config/search/path`, I have set an alias from `node` to `home`.
  Unfortunately this just resulted in redirecting both `example.com` and `example.com/node` to `example.com/home`, showing the node list - not my front page.
- I tried with an alias from `node` to `<front>` (I don't know if that is even valid there). This almost worked, `/home` and `/node` both redirect to `example.com` showing the right page. But now the node list is available at `/<front>` ...
- I also tried with panels, creating a variant of node template. Returning a status code when the  path was equals `node` did not work, I guess because the page is only triggered on `/node/`, with a slash. It won't let me create a panel just for the node path as the path is already in use of course.
- There doesn't seem to be any permission for setting access to this list.

So, how can I disable the page at `example.com/node`?
I guess my problem is I don't even know what kind of page this node list is. I have the feeling it's some unique page type, buried deep down in the core and can't be easily disabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're ok with writing a small [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) you could do it very easily using [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

The above will deny access to the page, if you want to remove it completely use this instead:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['node']);
}
```

There's a discussion on the subject [here](http://drupal.org/node/500296) with a few other ideas but I think this would be the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Node Page Disable](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_page_disable) contrib module from Drupal.org. 
And then just uncheck "*Retain /node as an active url?*" on page **Configuration > System > Site** information (`/admin/config/system/site-information`)
[image: Node Page Disable screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just set up an alias from `home` (*system path*) to `node` (*alias*) and it is working now. This is the opposite of what I've tried before. Both paths end up on `example.com` and show the correct new front page.

Anyway, this is probably just 'hiding' the system node at this url, so removing/denying access might be the better way to handle this.