# Disable node summary using Page Manager

Tags: 7, redirection, path-aliases

There are a few modules and methods specifically for disabling / removing the node summary page (at `/node`), like [Node Page Disable](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_page_disable), but I'm wondering if there's a way to redirect or override the page using the Page Manager module.

There's a good summary of other methods on [this stack exchange question and answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24132/disable-node-summary-page-on-node-path) and [this Drupal forum post](https://www.drupal.org/node/500296). One problem I'm running into with Page Manager is that the `/node/%node` path is already in use, and I'm not sure how to set it up for just the `/node` page without any additional arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with a variant. I've used that methodology on a personal project. Here are screenshots of the configuration.

The first variant (which returns a 404) checks, the node type (I have a content type called 'person'), the taxonomy terms applied to the node, and the role of the user.

[image: Page Manager config]

Comment: What's the page path for this? It looks like you're setting a variant for `/node/%node`, not just the `/node` page?