# How can I switch off the path /node/id

Tags: 8

I use the module pathauto for SEO-friendly path. So in general the user do not see  e.g. mydomain.de/node/8. But if the user type it by himself in the browser address he can see the change to alias in the browser address. How can I achieve that the user get the information "The requested page could not be found." or something else if he type e.g. /node/1, but NOT the information of alias or not existing node?

I tried to find a module. But there is no ready one. And I wondered using a block (see image) is not working. I do not know why, but this would solve my problem.[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to hide that path? There aren’t any technical or SEO reasons I can think of. I think it will be quite difficult to achieve what you’re asking

Comment: It is not only me looking for a solution. For former drupal versions I find this one https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/how-do-i-hide-the-default-page-node#1119. But it is not fitting for drupal 8

Comment: This might be a duplicate, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244257/disable-reaching-a-node-by-its-internal-path, depends on the conditions you want to block, you can't simply block all access to /node/id, then the site doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That is not the solution I am looking for, because it is only for role anonymus, depending on type and not in general. But the direction of this solution is good

Comment: @lesleyn that post is for a completely different thing - removing the /node page. You’re talking about removing the /node/123 page, but only when it’s accessed via a specific URL. That’s a very different problem and can’t be solved with access hooks. /node/123 and /alias-for-node-123 are the same entity. If one URL serves a 403/404, so does the other